# Variable Checkboxes PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a signup form that I am developing.  There is a section on this form called "Service Area".  What happens is the user enters a zip code and a mile radius and then an Ajax call pulls in all of the zip codes in that area and dynamically creates checkboxes on the page.  The user then selects which cities they service and submits the form.

Is there an easy way with PHP to know which checkboxes were checked? I have read a few guides and SO articles on passing along arrays with something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="serviceCity[]">
```

I cannot get this to work. Everytime I try, the `$_REQUEST["serviceCity"]` comes back as `undefined,` so I can's use a foreach to loop through. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: SO where's your code which generates checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create array postbacks in 2 ways, either explicitly:

```
<input name="checkbox[2]">
```

Or implicitly:

```
<input name"checkbox[]">
```

In the second case, they will be numbered upwards as encountered in the page.

Your real problem is probably using `$_REQUEST` which was deprecated somewhere in 2004, or perhaps earlier, as it is a grossly unsafe way to access 'GPC' variables, as they might overwrite eachother. Try using `$_POST` instead to read postback variables.

Comment: Thanks alot.  I had it set up as you had listed. What it ended up being was me pulling a prebuilt snippet out of another form I had used and not getting rid of some of the excess bits.  I was unaware that $_REQUEST was deprecated, as that is the way shop I work for does it.  Thank you very much for the information.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="serviceCity[]" value=""/>
```

**You can not access `serviceCity[]` value directly by using `$_REQUEST["serviceCity"]`.Here, `$_POST['serviceCity']` is an array so you can Fetch checkbox values by doing this :**

```
$cities = $_POST['serviceCity'];

foreach($cities as $service_cities)
        {

          echo $server_cities;

        }
```